# PHP Find same values in TWO multidimensional arrays and map them in separate array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays:

```
Array (
[1] => Array
    (   
    [id] => 1 
    [email] => aaa@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [id] => 2 
    [email] => bbb@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    )

[3] => Array
    (
    [id] => 3 
    [email] => ccc@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    ))
```

---

```
Array (
[1] => Array
    (   
    [id] => 4 
    [email] => aaa@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [id] => 5 
    [email] => bbb@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    )

[3] => Array
    (
    [id] => 6 
    [email] => ccc@mail.com

    some irrelevant pairs
    ))
```

As you see they both have key 'email' with the same values. How to extract the pairs of IDs as key-value pairs in the separate array as a map of the same emails ? I tried with foreach loops and in_array function, but something was wrong. This is what I need:

`Result (pairs of IDs where e-mail values are the same:
my_array_with_pairs_of_IDs = ( "1" => "4", "2" => "5", "3" => "6" );`

Please help, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is id unique in the arrays?

Comment: @Andreas yes, all the ids are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance optimized, based on @Andreas answer:

```
$map1 = array_column($arr1, 'id', 'email');
$map2 = array_column($arr2, 'id', 'email');

$result = [];

foreach ($map1 as $email => $id)
{
    if (isset($map2[$email]))
    {
        $result[$id] = $map2[$email];
    }
}
```

- removed `$arr1` and `$arr2` overriding;
- added `$result` declaration.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_column to make two flat arrays that you can use array_search in.
If array_search returns not false, it's the key of the found match.

```
$arr1 = array_column($arr1, 'email', 'id');
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, 'email', 'id');

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
    $find = array_search($val, $arr2);
    if($find !==false) $result[$key] = $find;
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["1 "]=>
  string(2) "4 "
  ["2 "]=>
  string(2) "5 "
  ["3 "]=>
  string(2) "6 "
}
```

https://3v4l.org/6XhUd

Comment: Thank you for very much! this outputs: $result  [1] => 0, [2] => 1, [3] => 2, but based on your answer user1597430 gave the answer that outputs: $result  [1] => 4, [2] => 5, [3] => 6;

Comment: @MirjanaKatalina no it doesn't! Look at the link posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method and store data in new array

```
$result = [];
foreach($a1 as $a){
   foreach($b1 as $b){
      if($b[email] == $a[email])
         $result[] = [$a[id]=>$b[id]];
   }
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but outputs result in separate arrays, not in the single array. Thank you, anyway!